# MySQL stored function with nested IF... ELSE IF... END IF

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

On my database MySQL 8.0.12 version I have this stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_test`(
IN spsID VARCHAR(255),
IN spsName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

DECLARE m LONGTEXT;

FLUSH HOSTS;

IF spsID <> "-" THEN 
   SET spsID = spsID; 
   SET m = CONCAT('AND sID = \'',spsID,'\'');
ELSE IF spsName <> "-" THEN 
   SET spsName = spsName;
   SET m = CONCAT('AND sName = \'',spsName,'\'');
END IF;
END IF;

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `tbl_a` t WHERE 1 ',m,';');

SELECT @s;

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`s`;
SET @`s` := NULL;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Executing the SP sending `2022-0001` for `spsID` value and `foo` for `spsName` value I expected this return

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_a` t WHERE 1 AND sID = '2022-0001' AND sName = 'foo';
```

Instead I have this return

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_a` t WHERE 1 AND sID = '2022-0001';
```

What's wrong with this SP?

Any help really appreciated...

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_a` t WHERE 1 AND sID = '2022-0001' AND sName = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of 1 IF-ELSE-ENDIF block you should have 2 different IF-ELSE blocks. Apart from this, You should have concatenated variable m along with CONCAT condition -

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_test`(
IN spsID VARCHAR(255),
IN spsName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

DECLARE m LONGTEXT DEFAULT '';

FLUSH HOSTS;

IF spsID <> "-" THEN 
   SET spsID = spsID; 
   SET m = CONCAT(m, 'AND sID = \'', spsID, '\'');
END IF;

IF spsName <> "-" THEN 
   SET spsName = spsName;
   SET m = CONCAT(m, 'AND sName = \'', spsName, '\'');
END IF;

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `tbl_a` t WHERE 1 ',m,';');

SELECT @s;

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`s`;
SET @`s` := NULL;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/UI007F1Y)

Comment: Thanks for help. I have tried your suggestion. Now error is `Procedure execution failed
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1`

Comment: Can you just update the IF-ELSE condition in your code and execute the procedure in your working code.

Comment: Got it. I forgot to initialize the variable m. I have updated the code now.